# json to 2d javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following external json file but in much larger sizes that look like this:

```
[{"time":1610.5,"Irradiance":1360.6718}
,{"time":1611.5,"Irradiance":1360.6549}
,{"time":1612.5,"Irradiance":1361.0528}]
```

I'd like to have a function that converts these to a javascript array that looks like this:

```
[[1610.5, 1360.6718],
 [1611.5, 1360.6549],
 [1612.5, 1361.0528]]
```

I'd also like to be able to extract the key names "time" and "Irradiance".

Comment: I'm new to this and don't quite get how to loop through and extract just the value and create a new array of arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var js=[{"time":1610.5,"Irradiance":1360.6718},{"time":1611.5,"Irradiance":1360.6549}
,{"time":1612.5,"Irradiance":1361.0528}];
var newarr=Array();
for(var i=0;i<js.length;i++)
{
    arr=new Array(js[i].time,js[i].Irradiance);
    newarr.push(arr);        
}
console.log(newarr);
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/kfaWx/

Comment: awesome this is what I'd been trying to get at but couldn't figure out thanks

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your array is named `data`:

```
converted = data.map(function(x) { return [x.time, x.Irradiance]; });
```

---

**EDIT** Extracting keys requires the assumption that the objects in the array are homogeneous.

```
var keys = [];
for (var k in data[0]) { keys.push(k); }
```

Now the array `keys` will contain the keys that are found in `data[0]`; i.e., `['time', 'Irradiance']`. Note, that if your [environment supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_support), you can also do:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
```

Comment: cool that works, now how could I extract the key names supposing those changed with various data sets